# Can you answer, WHAT AM I?

Tags: riddle

> I only have one colour, but I have many sizes
>
> I stay in the sunshine, but not in the rain
>
> I don't harm anyone and no one can harm me

**What am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a

> shadow

Hints

I have only one colour, many sizes

> A shadow has one colour (black) and only changes its shape and size.

I stay in the sunshine, don't stay in the rain

> Only where is light can be shadow.

I don't harm anyone, no one can also harm me

> You cant touch a shadow as it is not really something that is there, only the absence of light.

Comment: Isn’t this wildly inaccurate though, if we were to bring real world phenomena into this? (I’m not claiming that we should, but from a puzzlologically theoretical viewpoint, we might want to consider it.) Some counterexamples would be stained glass casting a colored shadow, plants dying from lack of light, and it being not at all uncommon to have rain showers while the sun constantly shines.

Comment: While that is true I think it is in the quality of the riddle how accurate the answer has to be (also cant demand to be too accurate or you wont solve the riddle). I am just playing the game, I didnt make the rules :)